# MySQL to MSSQL synchronization

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

I am trying to synchronise the data from `MySQL` to `MSSQL`.
Since my access on `MySQL` is limited to `Read only` I am trying to figure out how to sync the data between them.
I tried the **DBConvert** software which is good only for the initial replication. I know also about linked servers in SQL but this seems to synchronise data from `MSSQL` to `MySQL` and not vice versa.
Is there any other way(or software) to accomplish that?

Comment: Hi @BlackM, perhaps this article would help you? http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: Hi @Evaldas and thanks for your reply.. What I need is to sync all the data on MSSQL and not be able to query through SQL Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a software called **SQL Data Examiner 2012**. It's very good for this job but it's not cheap.
I used the command line version which I scheduled with Task Scheduler of Windows and I did some optimisations how to sync the data.